Multiple logistic regression with ordinal predictors
I'm looking for resources on general guidance for how to perform and interpret multiple logistic regression using SPSS, with ordinal predictors. I have 2 ordinal predictor variable. Each ordinal predictor has three groups or categories. (My outcome is binary, yes or no.) Each predictor category are likert-type categories.
Predictor 1
Unlikely, Neither likely or unlikely, Likely
Predictor 2
Slightly concerned, Somewhat concerned, Very concerned

You do not describe how your two predictor variables are encoded, but assuming they are encoded something like $1, 2, 3$ or $0,1,2$, then the $\beta$s for the predictors have the same interpretation as any predictor variable in a multiple logistic regression: a 1-unit increase in the predictor is associated with a $\beta$-unit change in the log-odds of your $y$ variable, while holding the value of the other predictor(s) constant..

What @Alexis suggests works but doesn't guarantee the effect of the ordinal predictor is monotonic. For this you'd need something other than treating the ordered levels as unordered factors. If you are open to doing a Bayesian analysis, take a look at this paper: Bürkner, P.-C. and Charpentier, E. (2020), Modelling monotonic effects of ordinal predictors in Bayesian regression models. The case study models a subjective pain measure as a function of the difficulty to perform a physical activity as measured on a 5-point scale (from "no problem" to "complete problem").

@dipetkov thank you, this helps a lot conceptually. But, I'm looking for more hands on guidance for interpretation of results. I have run applying the standard frequentist approach for now. I want to get this down before I jump into the non-frequentist approach.

@dipetkov Of course all the usual assumptions in logistic regression still hold, including the linearity assumption within the logit link. Frequentist models can also get more explicit about modeling monotonic/non-monotonic effects.

@Alexis Sure but I only know of {brms} of being able to handle ordinal predictors. Will be glad to learn of non-Bayesian implementations and articles (though I use R, clearly, not SPSS).

@Alexis I ran on SPSS treating my ordinal IVs at categorical. This gave me a beta coefficient for the first two categories, and treated the last as baseline. Do you think I should run again NOT treating my ordinal IVs as categorical. So that I will have a single beta coefficient, and can interpret as you described in your first post?

If your predictors have a natural order to them, then treating them as more continuous makes more sense, and can be interpreted much like any other predictor in a regression. The problem with treating them as categorical is that this assumes that each level is independent of each other. This is likely not true. As an example, suppose we have a measure of anxiety, where:

Very calm
Somewhat calm
Neutral
Somewhat anxious
Very anxious

Then the levels naturally are connected. It is easy to sense that being very anxious is qualitatively more anxious than somewhat anxious, and being somewhat anxious is qualitatively more anxious than neutral. So we can consider these on a spectrum that varies between being calm and being anxious, almost like a dial which we can turn from one point to the next. Per the comments, interpretation means:

A 1-unit increase in the predictor is associated with a $\beta$-unit change in the log-odds of your $y$ variable, while holding the value of the other predictor(s) constant.

Treating them categorically treats them as separate, isolated bins (e.g. very anxious is its own bin while somewhat anxious is it's own bin). This estimates the conditional mean of each level and contrasts against a baseline rather than the general trend of increases/decreases in anxiety. I'm guessing this is not the best way to treat your predictors, and the continuous case is more helpful.
